# Update individual span tags counting upwards from x seconds

Tags: jquery

I have several `<span>` tags that hold seconds.
Example:
    `<span class="timeout">27</span>`
    `<span class="timeout">58</span>`

I am trying to increment them by 1 second each time, but I am having some difficulties, namely, it puts wrong data in the `<span>` tags.

I must be doing something wrong, below is the code I am trying to use..
It must be wrong and full of mistakes, but well, I'm still trying to learn it ;-)

```
function timer() {
    var self = $(this);
    var idx  = $("span.timeout");
    var sec = parseInt(self.find('span.timeout').text())
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        idx.each(function() {
            idx.text(sec++)
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

Thanks in advance,
- Robert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to do it this way:

```
function timer() {
    var self = $(this);
    var idx = $("span.timeout");
    //console.log(self.find('span.timeout').text()); //gets you nothing
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        idx.text(function (_, txt) { //use .text()
            return parseInt(txt, 10) + 1; //convert the current text to int and increment it.
        });
    }, 1000);
}
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emQvt/)**

Your issue is here `var sec = parseInt(self.find('span.timeout').text())` self it nothing but a window in your case and you are trying to find spans in them and getting the text of it. Which gets you nothing and you are doing a  `parseInt` on nothing which gets you `NAN` and you are then using it for calculation, which is wrong. So you can use the callback of the text function and get the current textvalue of that span and then return the updated value for that span.

Comment: Adding a bit of explanation $("span.timeout") Returns a collection not a single element, you need to iterate through them using .each():

Comment: @PatsyIssa well you dont need to use each, because .text always use .each underneath

Comment: @PatsyIssa As long as the answer explains everything i don't think ther is an issue where the code is and where the explanation is. And well edit facility is there for a PURPOSE.. :)

Comment: @PatsyIssa well also your first comment as well is terribly wrong here... That is not his issue at all...

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly, I don't know if I can ask here, or if I need to make a new question, but how would I convert the seconds to `m:ss`? for example 0:42 or 2:42. Thanks, Robert.